# Add multiple rows to pandas dataframe via running function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm running this function 5 times with the hope that my dataframe will have 5 rows. However, it only saves the last row. Can anybody see the problem? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

(Yes this is crude but I've tried too many things at this point)

```
def Bucket(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, name, name_total, name_unprocessed, insideframe, counter):    
    for num1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=a")]' %name):
        print('%s a: ' %name + num1.text)
        name_unprocessed = num1.text
    for num2 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=b")]' %name):
        print('%s b: ' %name + num2.text) 
    for num3 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=c")]' %name):
        print('%s c: '%name + num3.text) 
    for num4 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=d")]' %name):
        print('%s d: ' %name + num4.text) 
    for num5 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=e")]' %name):
        print('%s e: ' %name + num5.text)
    for num6 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=f")]' %name):
        print('%s f: ' %name + num6.text) 
    for num7 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=g")]' %name):
        print('%s g: ' %name + num7.text)
    for num8 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=Duplicate")]' %name):
        print('%s h: ' %name + num8.text)
    name_total = int(num1.text)+int(num2.text)+int(num3.text)+int(num4.text)+int(num5.text)+int(num6.text)+int(num7.text)+int(num8.text)
    print('%s Total: ' %name + str(name_total))


    DF2 = {'a': ['%s' % Time],
            'b': ['%s' % Date],
            'c': ['%s' % Day],
            'd': ['%s' % int(num1.text)],
            'e': ['%s' % int(num2.text)],
            'f': ['%s' % int(num3.text)],
            'g': ['%s' % int(num4.text)],
            'h': ['%s' % int(num5.text)],
            'i': ['%s' % int(num6.text)],
            'j': ['%s' % int(num7.text)],
            'k': ['%s' % int(num8.text)],
            'Total': ['%s' % name_total],
            'Bucket': ['%s' % name]}
    frame2 = DataFrame(DF2)

    if counter == 0:
        SMSdf = insideframe.append(frame2)
        SMS.df = DataFrame(SMSdf, columns=['Time', 'Date', 'Day', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
        SMS.df.to_excel('Sprint_Log.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', index=False)
    else:
        SMSdf = SMSdf.append(frame2)
        SMS.df = DataFrame(SMSdf, columns=['Time', 'Date', 'Day', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
        SMS.df.to_excel('Log.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', index=False)

    counter=+1

Bucket(...1)
Bucket(...2)
Bucket(...3)
Bucket(...4)
Bucket(...5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each call to

```
SMS.df.to_excel('Log.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', index=False)
```

overwrites `Log.xlsx` if it already exists.  This is why only the last row is saved.

[Per the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html),

> If passing an existing ExcelWriter object, then the sheet will be added to the
>   existing workbook.  This can be used to save different DataFrames to one
>   workbook:

```
>>> writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

---

Therefore, you should define the writer *once* outside of `Bucket`, pass the writer to `Bucket`, and use `SMS.df.to_excel(writer, sheet, index=False)`.
Note that you also need to write to a different sheet with each call to `Bucket`.

```
import pandas as pd

def Bucket(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, name, name_total, name_unprocessed, insideframe, counter, writer):    
    ...
    else:
        SMSdf = SMSdf.append(frame2)
        SMS.df = pd.DataFrame(SMSdf, columns=['Time', 'Date', 'Day', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
        sheet = 'Sheet {}'.format(counter)
        SMS.df.to_excel(writer, sheet, index=False)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for counter in range(1, 6):
    Bucket(..., counter, writer)
writer.save()
```

---

Here is a simple runnable example which saves two dataframes to one `xlsx` file, then reads them back:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,4)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,6)))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/tmp/output.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()

reader = pd.ExcelFile('/tmp/output.xlsx')
for sheet in reader.sheet_names:
    df = reader.parse(sheet)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tried this and its still saving only the last line. I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: My mistake. You must also change the value of `sheet` -- the second argument to `to_excel`. Otherwise, we would just be overwriting the same sheet.  I've edited the post to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, unutbu, unfortunately it is still only saving the last line

Comment: I've added a runnable example which saves two DataFrames to one xlsx file. It then parses each sheet of the xlsx file into a DataFrame and prints it out. You might want to run that to make sure things are working as advertised. If it does work, then compare your code to this example to find the source of the error. If you can't find it, I think we'd need to see a [minimal runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to find the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I went with saving the dataframes inbetween each run of the Bucket function. I posted my answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to save into the same dataframe on the same excel sheet.

```
def Bucket(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, name, name_total, name_unprocessed, insideframe):    
    for num1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=a")]' %name):
        print('%s a: ' %name + num1.text)
        name_unprocessed = num1.text
    for num2 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=b")]' %name):
        print('%s b: ' %name + num2.text) 
    for num3 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=c")]' %name):
        print('%s c: '%name + num3.text) 
    for num4 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=d")]' %name):
        print('%s d: ' %name + num4.text) 
    for num5 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=e")]' %name):
    print('%s e: ' %name + num5.text)
    for num6 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=f")]' %name):
        print('%s f: ' %name + num6.text) 
    for num7 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=g")]' %name):
        print('%s g: ' %name + num7.text)
    for num8 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a [contains(@href, "%s&singleTopic=1&dashboardSort=Duplicate")]' %name):
        print('%s h: ' %name + num8.text)
    name_total = int(num1.text)+int(num2.text)+int(num3.text)+int(num4.text)+int(num5.text)+int(num6.text)+int(num7.text)+int(num8.text)
   print('%s Total: ' %name + str(name_total))


    DF2 = {'a': ['%s' % Time],
        'b': ['%s' % Date],
        'c': ['%s' % Day],
        'd': ['%s' % int(num1.text)],
        'e': ['%s' % int(num2.text)],
        'f': ['%s' % int(num3.text)],
        'g': ['%s' % int(num4.text)],
        'h': ['%s' % int(num5.text)],
        'i': ['%s' % int(num6.text)],
        'j': ['%s' % int(num7.text)],
        'k': ['%s' % int(num8.text)],
        'Total': ['%s' % name_total],
        'Bucket': ['%s' % name]}
    Bucket.frame2 = DataFrame(DF2)

Bucket(...1)
SMSdf = insideframe.append(Bucket.frame2)
Bucket(...2)
SMSdf = SMSdf.append(Bucket.frame2)
Bucket(...3)
SMSdf = SMSdf.append(Bucket.frame2)
Bucket(...4)
SMSdf = SMSdf.append(Bucket.frame2)
Bucket(...5)
SMSdf = SMSdf.append(Bucket.frame2)
```